# full setup for configuraton of local host

Tags: php

my project is saved in c:/wamp/www/EducationPortal
now in browser i want to open file with www.eportal.com

i have already make changes in httpd.conf with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/EducationPortal"
    ServerName www.eportal.com
#    ServerAlias www.site1.dev
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/EducationPortal">
    AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now what should i do further?

Comment: Use `vhosts` and add the entry `127.0.0.1 www.eportal.com` to your hosts file.

Comment: what changes require in httpd.conf???

Answer (score 0):

You need to access hosts file and edit it too. The file is found at: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and it is named `hosts` without extension.

It seems like the following:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       larablog.fox
127.0.0.1      phpmyadmin.fox
127.0.0.1     cake241.fox
```

Comment: can you tell me file names with path?

Comment: hosts file is in .ics and not able to save

Comment: You could able to change the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Change the httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/test"
ServerName www.test.com

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/test">
  AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from ::1
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Step: 2

Edit the lhost file which will be available in

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**
 NOTE: if you cant edit the file, you have to open that file as an administrator

1. Open Notepad with Administrative privileges by clicking Start, All Programs, Accessories, and then right-click Notepad and select to open as Administrator.
2. Now that Notepad is open with Administrative privileges browse to (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) in Notepad and open the hosts file.

then put an entry like

```
127.0.0.1     test.com
```

**Restart your server** That's it